# How to auto-expand all "older posts" on Facebook wall

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to automatically expand all "older posts" on a Facebook wall at once? I'm using Firefox if it matters.

Comment: This question's accepted and alternate answer are no longer valid.  Can anyone provide an updated answer?

Answer (score 6):

As you are using Firefox you can install the Better Facebook! Firefox Add-on.

[Firefox Add-on Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/52369/versions/?page=1#version-4.300)

The add-on provides numerous features/enhancements.  One of these being

> Automatically click "Older Posts" link on the home page [x] times to get more posts

This should provide you with the functionality that your require.

[image]

You can actually install this on Firefox, Chrome, Safari & Opera.  The website for further information [can be found here](http://betterfacebook.net/)

Comment: Better Facebook! does not appear to offer this option any longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run [this script](https://gist.github.com/1260847) in the console.

And as of 30/04/2013, the id has changed. The valid code is now:

```
//Run this on the person's facebook profile page to expand the wall
var INTERVAL=2000; // Time between wall expansions, in milliseconds
var MAX_TRIES=150; // How many times to try expanding the wall

function expand(){
var foo=document.getElementById('pagelet_group_pager').children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].onclick;
if (typeof(foo)!='undefined'){
foo();
}
}
for (var i = 1; i < MAX_TRIES; i++){
setTimeout(expand,i*INTERVAL);
}
```

Comment: Facebook has gone through a number of iterations since 2011. Does this script have a chance of still being relevant?

Comment: It does not work presently (in Chrome, which shouldn't make a difference).  *VM845:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null*