# Show all posts and comments in a Facebook group that I am a member of, not an admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am a member of a group and I would like to see all the posts and comments from the beginning of the group (approx 8 months ago). Is there a way that I can do this without spending hours simply scrolling and expanding manually?

Comment: Maybe check out this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8336/how-to-auto-expand-all-older-posts-on-facebook-wall it may help solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://sociograph.io provides full content export for Facebook groups and pages.
The exported data includes all posts and comments for the entire group/page history as 2 CSV files. Posts and comments metadata such as author, creation date, number of reaction per post is included as well. 
Full content export is a premium feature, short sample export is available for free

P.S. I'm the founder of the service

Comment: Please disclose in your answer if you are affiliated with the product in any way.

Comment: Looking over the other questions that you answered with this product, I think that this is the only one it actually applies to.  Please don't use answers just to advertise your product.

Comment: From reading the text on the homepage, it seems this is for pages you own, not for pages you use but don't own which is the OP's problem. Also when I tried to sign into it, it said the app is not currently available.